# Install imagemagick command line tools only?

Tags: 21.10, imagemagick

I installed `imagemagick` using...

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends imagemagick
```

This also installs a graphical application which can be launched from the Apps Grid. (The app launcher is `display-im6.q16.desktop`).

However, is there a way to only install `imagemagick` command line tools without the GUI application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing without that tool: not directly. This is the way the package `imagemagick` is packaged. Installing it installs different binaries, including `display-im6.q16`, a graphical tool that is exposed in the menu system through the installation of a .desktop launcher, `/usr/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop`.

While you could delete the executable and the desktop file, that is not a good idea. You should stay out of directories managed by the APT packaging system. You also may not be willing to customize the installation `deb` yourself not to install that part.

You, however, can get rid of the entry in your menu system. The easiest way probably is to install a tool like "menulibre" or "alacarte" and disable the menu item there.

If you do not want to install an extra tool, you need to manually copy and edit the `.desktop` launcher file.

1. Copy the file `/usr/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop` to your `~/.local/share/applications` directory. `.local` is a hidden folder in your home directory. Find `share` in that folder and then `applications`. Create that folder if it does not exist.
2. Edit the copy `~/.local/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop` in a text editor and add the line "Hidden=true". That disables the launcher. Save the changes

It will be disabled for your user only. If you want it to be disabled for all users on the system, copy the modified `.desktop` file to `/usr/local/share/applications`. You need to be administrator for that.

Answer (score 1):

The ImageMagick [website](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) has a downloadable AppImage which is command line only, just make it executable and put it in a folder on your $PATH, like `/usr/local/bin`.

The downside to this approach is that all the tools are condensed into a single file, so you have to prepend all commands with "magick ", e.g. `$magick convert foo.jpg bar.png` instead of `$convert foo.jpg bar.png`.

Comment: I didn't know there was a downloadable appimage. This is a good tip, however @vanadium's answer directly answered my question.